# ARM Template, output to pass onto next deployment

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I am trying to create an Azure Firewall using an ARM Template. Part of the deployment requires me to pass in the destination address of a DNAT rule. This needs to be the public IP of the Firewall. But I don't know the value until the public IP of the firewall is created which is part of the firewall deployment.

How do I take the public IP of the firewall public IP and pass to the DNAT rule? I've tried referencing the IP using .IpAddress but I get ipAddress is not a valid parameter.

```
                            "destinationAddresses": [
                            "Needs to be Public IP"
                        ],
```

This is the error is get when trying to reference the IP

```
The language expression property 'ipAddress' can't be evaluated.'
```

Im using this to create the IP:

```
  {
  "name": "[concat(variables('publicIPNamePrefix'), add(copyIndex(), 1))]",
  "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses",
  "apiVersion": "2019-04-01",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "sku": {
    "name": "Standard"
  },
  "properties": {
    "publicIPAllocationMethod": "Static",
    "publicIPAddressVersion": "IPv4"
  },
  "copy": {
    "name": "publicIpCopy",
    "count": "[parameters('numberOfPublicIPAddresses')]"
  }
```

},

Any help would be amazing. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to do something like this:

```
reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Resources/deployments', 'previous_deployment_name'), '2017-05-10').outputs.%OUTPUT_NAME%.value
```